# What is causing a SIGSEGV in mono_class_vtable_full in Unity for Android?

Tags: unity, c#, android, mono

I'm a developer of a mobile game, and we have Crashlytics in our game.

For the latest release for Android, we are having crash reports with the following stack trace, for a number of players:

```
Caused by java.lang.Error: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000054
Build fingerprint: 'samsung/j7veltedx/j7velte:8.1.0/M1AJQ/J701FXXU6BRL1:user/release-keys'
Revision: '3'
pid: 10762, tid: 11403, name: UnityMain  >>> com.tod.xameen <<<
r0 00000000  r1 00000000  r2 00000001  r3 00000000
r4 d2145c4c  r5 00000001  r6 12f94a00  r7 12c80138
r8 00000000  r9 e674d600  sl 130bd128  fp d07ed36c
ip cfb4fbc4  sp d07ed350  lr cf9cf30c  pc cf9cf354  cpsr 0000004d

   at libmonobdwgc-2.mono_class_vtable_full(mono_class_vtable_full:180)
   at libmonobdwgc-2.mono_array_new_checked(mono_array_new_checked:132)
   at libmonobdwgc-2.mono_array_new(mono_array_new:40)
   at libunity.00520150(Unknown Source)
```

In our latest release, we upgraded a few of our external SDKs and libraries that may have caused this.

How can I find out the cause and fix it?